# Display values on click on lightning button icon

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-buttonicon

I am using a lightning button icon in an html table in Salesforce Lightning Component just like the example given in the documentation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonIcon/example

What I want to understand is that Can I show values like edit or delete once I click on the icon?  Or do I have to create a custom component for that?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the [lightning-button-menu](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-menu/example) or [lightning:buttonMenu](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonMenu/example) components. These provide an icon choice, a dropdown menu, and events you can respond to when a menu item is used.